# Call for a static function that exists in inheritance classes

Tags: typescript, function, inheritance, static

Suppose I have this inheritance tree, with a static sample function that exists in the classes `D.ts`, `E.ts`, `F.ts`, `G.ts`:

[image]

I want the `thisIsTestFunction ()` to be a static function and not an abstract function, I don't want this function appear in the bases classes (A, B, C)!

I created an array and I want to run the array in a loop and call the static function:

```
let objects : A = new Array(20);

for (const object of objects ) {
           // object.thisIsTestFunction(); ??
           // How call the function here ?
}
```

I try to call the function with `object.constructor.name` but it doesn't working.

I know that a static function can only be called using the class name, But abstract function is not a good solution for me, I want the function to appear only once in each class and be a static function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue that prevents the compiler from understanding what you're doing is that the `constructor` property of an object is not strongly typed.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#3851](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) for more information.  Right now, `object.constructor` is just typed as `Function`, which isn't known to have a `thisisTestFunction()` method.  One thing you can do is manually give every concrete class an appropriate strongly-typed `constructor` property, but this is tedious (and has some gotchas about subclassing that I won't go into here):

```
class D extends C {
    public static thisisTestFunction() {
        alert("Testing");
    }    
    ["constructor"]: typeof D // here
}
```

And then if you had an object of, say, type `D` you could do this:

```
const d = new D();
d.constructor.thisisTestFunction(); // okay
```

---

Another problem is that with an array of objects of type `A`, the compiler has no way to know that each element will definitely be one of `D`, `E`, `F`, or `G`.  TypeScript has no concept of a `final` class (see [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863)), and even if it did it wouldn't necessarily be able to represent that the `A` hierarchy is "sealed":

```
class Oops extends A {
    ["constructor"]: typeof Oops;
    // no static function here
}

let someObjects: A[] = new Array(20);
someObjects.push(new Oops()); // what if the array contains an Oops?
for (const object of someObjects) {
    object.constructor.thisisTestFunction(); // still error
}
```

Instead, you might want to tell the compiler that your array contains elements not of type `A`, but of one of the particular concrete subclasses of `A` that you care about:

```
type ConcreteA = D | E | F | G;
let objects: ConcreteA[] = new Array(20);
objects.push(new Oops()); // error now to do this
for (const object of objects) {
    object.constructor.thisisTestFunction(); // okay
}
```

The `ConcreteA` type is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of `D`, `E`, `F`, and `G`, and as long as each one of those has a strongly-typed `constructor` that knows about the `thisisTestFunction()` static method, then it will work without error.

---

As an aside, if the implementation of `thisisTestFunction()` is truly identical in each concrete subclass, you might consider putting that static function up in `A` anyway, and mark the method as requiring that its `this` context (as represented by a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)) correspond to a concrete constructor:

```
abstract class A {
    public static thisisTestFunction<T extends new (...args: any) => A>(this: T) {
        alert("Testing");
    }
}
```

This is less code, and TypeScript will complain if you try to call it on `A`, `B`, or `C`, but allow it on `D`, through `G`:

```
A.thisisTestFunction(); // error!
B.thisisTestFunction(); // error!
D.thisisTestFunction(); // okay
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5YyDeBYAUE-SIARlAC4BOCpS8ANiFFEgIJLZ4GchIC8SAjAG5cnAL64RBYmUrxqdBkwDCSCAA9SEYABMmrdp07xeSAMzCO+cTkn5pFKjXqMkAIVUatulm1uGiJgBMFmISNpZOikgAIh6aOsq+EZzaJgAsIYb4MACuRLQAlsZkIKRFSKQAFgVQNQAq0KQAYjnAcgUA9sAAFACUSVlZILQQ5KTdAEQNZAXAAOYTvZlZ1n6cANoT8F0yOXId5BMAugBcFQCeMBAdAGYxfqsR28BkSKl86ADuMX3LbwB0z12+3I-yqNXqjRabTKXV+SAA9AikB0ANYgc5hIzOJgAUTiXkSBkGyD4AFY-pxcvlyiUysZwbUoNNmq12nD+sTBlIRmNJizZgslmsCNZuZsgRQ9qQDsczqRLtc7riHliCAoXE0CQk3ANBnc+AA2SkEamFYqkUrlRmQsjQ9k9Tkioa88ZTRqCxYmqxqrISnZSkFyi5XW5IJqq8LYqIAcW13ncXMMcxMAHZvUgzbTLfSKtUmSz7bDHXruXZXfyPfMvc6kI9xVsA+RpbLTiGlUgY396+qcagOjAmOp4t59LX-S9AzLDm2FaG7igB1AM0ikMAOkg6eUbmzi0hKqMIJG-CNqFAOpAUEQAFYQORQM7MdZHExfFjkSjnbqBAAMwoi56Xjed6kFA-y5FAlTdG+i6Dn0-6cDcBxIN0koosBcgoncgEQFet73k6yQEB0GGkICTYtqCNrMlCu6dI6giIsiMy0LQqgfgcx5RgQc7IEoXTwOQECaKwfCxAAPkg+KSVqkldiewnofhoFnPxbRCSJz6vhA3zMB+GLfn+fwkcpYEQVBMFLvBjGrqM5DIeu3wym8G6Mn4SHkChaEmSBWFKSBUCEdyPlyORk7NiCYL5rarIwvR8KrmiGKRtYoCQLACDIHUnwbkm9iyPIfZjkRdgmEItZZhaVoMtFNF2nRXQADx1PGTBvt0-ydSA5BzA+hDAOc-Q8AAfCww3dIyZx1EFZblqMboCtWCGDGKoq+oQJAOJhGqJMOhI+EmRgmOYXFcJtBWRC47h7TqxXcgEfDBFxfg7TErVICoh0EO8SAZOOjbhZRwa8WG0SneqAZvNp3zRL8fjaGFwLTlFEJ1bFDoJciSWYtx+CvfiN3eJ9takkgFL-ZKEXTsDiphiqEQ9njfZaoTTCJrWBpIMaFMUUGs603cEYM+tr1xqzupffgKZ8OmPOA3z8oC523brcwKMFrRcUcjZyJ2QcACEfiuOrMVFvFSxMex9nkIbETRCbaNm9rlvY+tvEfQJGkQKJb2SdJ4ZIHJfynv596qZ7wne1pHw6e+n6Gct+AeV5kMhdQYZp4FpaGGniNTgcDuFg1DEu+iOOhDgohAA)